# How to return Int from ActionListener?

Tags: java, return, actionlistener

I created a little code with visual interface using JFrame... you can type in a date and hit the conformation button. The problem is that I can't return the values out of the ActionListener... cause its a void of cause, I also tried to declare the variables outside of the ActionListener, but I get an Error like not possible from inner function or so. Any Ideas?

Heres a part of my code and a screenshot:

```
DVDAddenButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                //((DefaultListModel)Liste.getModel()).addElement();
                String Mediumtitel = DVDTextfeld.getText();

                int DVDAusleihdatumZahlTag = 0;
                int DVDAusleihdatumZahlMonat = 0;
                int DVDAusleihdatumZahlJahr = 0;
                String DVDAusleihdatumStringTag = "";
                String DVDAusleihdatumStringMonat = "";
                String DVDAusleihdatumStringJahr = "";
                DVDAusleihdatumStringTag = DVDAusleihdatumFeldTag.getText();
                DVDAusleihdatumStringMonat = DVDAusleihdatumFeldMonat.getText();
                DVDAusleihdatumStringJahr = DVDAusleihdatumFeldJahr.getText();
                try{
                    DVDAusleihdatumZahlTag = Integer.parseInt(DVDAusleihdatumStringTag);
                    DVDAusleihdatumZahlMonat = Integer.parseInt(DVDAusleihdatumStringMonat);
                    DVDAusleihdatumZahlJahr = Integer.parseInt(DVDAusleihdatumStringJahr);
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException ex){}
                if (DVDAusleihdatumZahlTag < 32 && DVDAusleihdatumZahlTag > 0 && DVDAusleihdatumZahlMonat < 13 && DVDAusleihdatumZahlMonat > 0 && DVDAusleihdatumZahlJahr < date.getJahr()+1){
                    model.addElement(Mediumtitel);
                    model.addElement("Ausgeliehen am: " + DVDAusleihdatumZahlTag + "." + DVDAusleihdatumZahlMonat + "." + DVDAusleihdatumZahlJahr);
                    model.addElement(" ");
                    DatumFehler.setVisible(false);
                }
                else{
                    DatumFehler.setVisible(true);
                }
                }
        });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHDEd.png)

Sorry for messed up code..

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I tested it and upper case character variable name doesn't affect anything or make errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a new class, then create the class inside ActionListener, then your class stores the information. When you want to access it, just call it from the class.

Comment: Done. It works, thank u man u are my hero of the day ;)

Comment: glad to help :)